# Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in

Tags: php

I was setting up a user profile system using a tutorial, and I came across this PHP error.

//The first line is the one that gives the error

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql); 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo '<hr />';
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr><td>ID:</td><td>'.$row["id"].'</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Avatar:</td><td><img src="'.$row["avatar"].'" width="100px" /></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Firstname:</td><td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Lastname:</td><td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Country:</td><td>'.$row["country"].'</td></tr>';
            echo '</table>';

        }
    }
    else {
       echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post code  above `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` where `$result` is set.

Comment: I don't know. I'm new here and googling the error gives me fixes that dont work.

Comment: Your $results is not an object, but you are asking it's property "num_rows" like it is an object. Most likely you have check if you previous operation, where you get this $results, succeeded. Looks like this "$results" is not acquired well, but you are assuming it is.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

Comment: can you show whole code?

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE $result->num_rows with $result->num_rows(). because it is a function. I hope this will works for you.

```
$result->num_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
if ($result && ($result->num_rows() > 0)) 
{ 

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {

        echo '<hr />';
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><td>ID:</td><td>'.$row["id"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Avatar:</td><td><img src="'.$row["avatar"].'" width="100px" /></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Firstname:</td><td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Lastname:</td><td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Country:</td><td>'.$row["country"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';

    }
}
else {
       echo "0 results";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error probably happens when you have no results whatsoever, therefore you're trying to get a property of an empty object. As the comments mentioned above, first you should make sure that $results is not empty. Instead of:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Try:

```
if ($result && ($result->num_rows > 0)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";

      $result =  $con->query($lclQuery);

      if($result->rowCount() > 0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<hr />';
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><td>ID:</td><td>'.$row["id"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Avatar:</td><td><img src="'.$row["avatar"].'" width="100px" /></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Firstname:</td><td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Lastname:</td><td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Country:</td><td>'.$row["country"].'</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';

    }
}
else {
   echo "0 results";
}
```

Use Like Above. Above Code definitely work.